# Windows Forms - how to get the MDIparent Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, mdi

I have a `MDIform` application, where a form named `MainForm` is set to parent. Every time I open a new form I'm closing the others and I do it with custom method that gets 3 arguments one of which is `object` representing the `MDIparent`. Mostly I open forms from my `MainForm` which is also a `MDIparent` but I have this situation where I have to open a child form form another child form. Let's say that if I call my method for opening a new form like :

> NewForm newForm = getMyForm(this, arg2, arg3)

when I'm in the `MainForm` which is also a parent it's easy. But how to call my method or how to pass the object which is my `MDIparent` when I'm calling from other child form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Form.MdiParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent.aspx) property which  will give you the `MDI Parent` for the current form.

```
MainForm frm = this.MdiParent as MainForm;
if(frm != null)
    //form found
```

Comment: Thanks. Very fast indeed :)

Comment: Now is even better. Thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry sir habib, but i think you dont need `if(frm != null)` `:D`

Comment: @spajce, the check is in place if the casting to `MainForm` failed.

Comment: yes, but the Casting is expected result, if you don't mind, is there  times the Casting will fail?

Comment: @spajce, yes there is always that chance, that casting may fail. Its always better to check if the casting is successful, may be in this particular case one can ignore it, but it is a good practice to check for null after casting with `as` operator

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like

From your `MainForm`

```
 var f = new NewForm() { MdiParent = this};
 f.Show();
```

as example of Mr. Habib, Take note that the `method` from the `MainForm` is must be a `public`.

```
MainForm frm = this.MdiParent as MainForm;
if(frm != null)
{
  frm.Methods(this, arg2, arg3)
}
```